# Unable to create ramdisk after updating to 2.6.32

Tags: debian, ramdisk, uuid

I've upgraded one of our servers (debian lenny) from backports. It upgraded the kernel to 2.6.32-trunk-amd64, and switched the disk access to UUID. Everything works fine, however, /dev/ram0 no longer gets created and I'm unable to see it in /dev/disk/by-uuid:

```
# ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/
  total 0
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 2010-11-02 10:20 0670c658-a28d-4e93-991c-7e270a1dfbf3 -> ../../sda3
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 2010-11-02 10:20 07DA-0A15 -> ../../sda1
  lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 2010-11-02 10:20 ba59116d-c127-431b-bc00-c2c676ea0cb6 -> ../../sda5
```

The ramdisk is defined in /boot/grub/menu.list as:

```
 kernel          /boot/vmlinuz-2.6.32-trunk-amd64 root=UUID=0670c658-a28d-4e93-991c-7e270a1dfbf3 ro quiet ramdisk_size=2000000
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see that -trunk- version in backports but the config file for `linux-image-2.6.32-bpo.5-amd64` says `CONFIG_BLK_DEV_RAM=m` so it appears that Debian is no longer building the ramdisk driver into the kernel.

Check and see if ramdisk is listed in /proc/devices.  If not, then if you *really* need a ramdisk, you'll need to load the rd kernel module with something like

```
insmod rd ramdisk_size=2000000
```

If you just want an in-memory filesystem, consider using tmpfs instead.

Comment: Thanks! You're right indeed, they dropped it from the kernel as a built-in.